# SVN - Adding a user

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn

A long time ago I setup SVN on my remote server. I connect to it locally from eclipse using

```
svn+ssh://kris@hostname:22/srv/svn/repo
```

I now need to add another user and I can't for the life of me work out how to do it. I can't even find where the current user account "kris" is located.

I am using
svn, version 1.6.11 (r934486)
   compiled May 14 2012, 05:36:26
http://subversion.tigris.org/

Comment: Um... [read the documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html)?  BTW, this is off-topic for SO.  Please (re)read the [FAQ] and [Ask]

Comment: @JimGarrison really very helpful Jim. Do you think I haven't been reading documentation for hours upon hours. I use a forum as a near last resort not a first

Comment: Well, one of the fundamental tenets of SO is "show your work", and you didn't give any indication you've done any research or tried anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking with my Linux guru he lead me to the solution.

I am not using SVN's authentication. I am using linux authentication so the steps are

Create a new linux user.
then add them to a group that has access to the single repository

useradd *username*

passwd *password*

groupadd *groupname*

vi /etc/group
look for *groupname*
add *username* to that line
chgrp -R *groupname* /repoLocation
chmod -R g+w /repoLocation

problem solved